# How do you convert a HashSet into an ArrayList in Java?

Tags: java, arraylist, hashset

I have a `HashSet<ArrayList<String>>` named possibleRoutes and want to convert it into type `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>`.

How do you convert a `HashSet<Arraylist<String>>` into `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>` in Java?

Comment: Have you looked at the javadoc of `ArrayList`?

Answer (score 6):

how bout:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> al = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>( hs);
```

Comment: What is `hs.elements`?  There's no such thing as `HashSet.elements`.

Comment: isn't there an .elements() method in the hs?   I'm mostly a c#,  but originally a java guy.... so sometimes I get confused.  =)

Comment: nope, there isn't you're right.  thx.

Answer (score 2):

```
 ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> list = 
    new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>(possibleRoutes);
```

Comment: I tried this but got the message: "The possibleRoutes may not have been initialized" and it was declared as a static type at the beginning.

Comment: How was `possibleRoutes` declared?  You're describing an issue with `possibleRoutes`, not with the copy.

Comment: It was first declared static HashSet<ArrayList<String>> as a global variable.